# Wireless stopped working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I never had any problems with Ubuntu for 2 years, but my WiFi randomly stopped working today.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed alongside Windows 10, and WiFi works on my Windows partition so I know it's not a hardware issue.

I tried navigating to System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers and I am able to see my Broadcom driver but it says "This device is not working."

Could someone please direct me how to fix this issue?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: My output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0623]
```

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS. With new kernels it does not let to load 3rd party drivers.

Comment: I have Secure Boot disabled and it is still not working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I have added the output.

Comment: the driver is not installed. Re-install it by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Comment: This fixed the problem. I had to connect with ethernet and then follow your instructions. Thanks